# Class.getConstructor and inheritence

Tags: java

I would like to use Class.getConstructor because I don't know what instances I need until run time.

I have a class A with a constructor A(Type1). Type2 extends Type1. Now, when I invoke A(Type2), the compiler intuits that I am actually invoking the constructor A(Type1) because A(Type2) doesn't exist. However, when I call A.class.getConstructor(Type2.class), I get a run time error saying that constructor A(Type2) does not exist. I can understand why this is happening, but I still want to supply a parameter of a subtype, and for the runtime to intuit the constructor required...

I don't really know what type of constructor I will need at run time (the simplified call to getConstructor above is only to indicate what is going on in my code) and I don't know whether, for instance, I will be instantiating an object of a subclass of A, or using a parameter of a subclass of Type1 (Type2, say, in the example). How do I get a similar thing to happen at run time as occurs at compile time?

Thanks for the help,

Owen.

Comment: Please post your actual class definitions and code that is behaving in a way you don't expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do this and get Java to do at runtime what the compiler does at compile-time is to use `java.beans.Expression`:

```
Type2 ctorArg = ...;
Expression expr = new Expression(A.class, "new", new Object[]{ctorArg});
A a = (A)expr.evaluate();
```

E&OE

Comment: Both solutions would appear to work (I've implemeted the first solution because it appears to be faster), but this one appears give me a solution to future problems like these that uses the same mechanism as the compiler uses. I.e., no wheels have to be reinvented.

Answer (score 0):

You may get all constructors and filter them to get the needed (it doesn't care about varargs, but I think, you may extend it this way):

```
Class<?> myClass = ...
Class<?>[] passedParams = ...
Constructor<?>[] constructors = myClass.getConstructors();
for (Constructor <?> constructor : constructors) {
    Class<?> receivedParams = constructor.getParameterTypes();
    if (passedParams.length != receivedParams.length) {
        continue;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < passedParams.length; ++i) {
        if (!passedParams[i].isAssignableFrom(receivedParams[i])) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    // Yep, here we got correct constructor!
    correctConstructors.add(constructor); // or whatever you like to do with it
}
```

docs: [`getConstructors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors()), [`isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Thanks. I think that'll work. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: @OwenThomas Don't just copy the code, it's an example of how it may work.

Comment: Yea yea. I think I can understand what it's doing. I'll adapt it to fit and get back to you to let you know whether it does the job. Thanks. :)

Comment: @OwenThomas don't be afraid to mark as the solution at the end :)

Comment: Although I had to use getConstructors in a different way to how you suggested (I'm checking that I only have one constructor, and that the constructor has, as a parameter, the same, or a superclass declaration, as "this" class) your suggestion to use getParameters does the trick. Thank you.